# Jquery Ui Tabs with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Jquery ui tabs not working in Wordpress, i have added this function to my 
functions.php

```
if( !is_admin()){
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"));
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
   wp_register_script('jquery-ui',("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"));
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
}
```

And  header.php

```
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going here. By default WordPress splits jQuery UI into its component parts and registers each part separately. The jQuery handle registered in WordPress actually registers two scripts: jquery-core and jquery-migrate. If you want to just deregister jQuery, use the jquery-core handle.

If you want to unload the WordPress jQuery UI delivered code, you first need to wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core') as there is no jquery-ui handle registered in WordPress.

You don't need the parens around the source urls in either of your wp_register_script lines:
wp_register_script('jquery', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js");

You should also include the dependency parameter when registering a jQuery-ui script, like this:

wp_register_script('jquery-ui','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

All of the jQuery UI handles pre registered in WordPress are below:

jquery-ui-core,
jquery-effects-core,
jquery-effects-blind,
jquery-effects-bounce,
jquery-effects-clip,
jquery-effects-drop,
jquery-effects-explode,
jquery-effects-fade,
jquery-effects-fold,
jquery-effects-highlight,
jquery-effects-pulsate,
jquery-effects-scale,
jquery-effects-shake,
jquery-effects-slide,
jquery-effects-transfer,
jquery-ui-accordion,
jquery-ui-autocomplete,
jquery-ui-button,
jquery-ui-datepicker,
jquery-ui-dialog,
jquery-ui-draggable,
jquery-ui-droppable,
jquery-ui-menu,
jquery-ui-mouse,
jquery-ui-position,
jquery-ui-progressbar,
jquery-ui-resizable,
jquery-ui-selectable,
jquery-ui-slider,
jquery-ui-sortable,
jquery-ui-spinner,
jquery-ui-tabs,
jquery-ui-tooltip,
jquery-ui-widget